# Messenger on different windows issue

Tags: javascript, php

I have a messenger on PHP/js, imported to all pages of the website. The messenger works through ajax, checking for new messages each 5 seconds.
Also I have desktop and sound notifications.

The problem is, if I opened multiple pages, and I'm currently on one of them, the reminder may come from another page, which is currently not active. However, inactive pages should notify only if the active page is not the same website.

Ideas?

Comment: `Ideas?` - Broadcast Channel API perhaps? which immediately removes the two worst browsers from the equation, but that's probably the best method you could use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for window focus:

```
var window_focus;

$(window).focus(function() {
    window_focus = true;
}).blur(function() {
    window_focus = false;
});
```

Check if location.host matches specified domain and window is focused:

```
if((location.host == "example.com")&&(window_focus == true))
{
    //window is focused and on specified domain for that website.
    //sounds, notifications, etc. here
}
```

Not completely sure if this is what you mean, but I hope it helps.